# Validate textbox input with List

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a password system of sorts.. I've a class with a list in it. It looks like this:

```
  public class LogInList
{
    public int AnsNr { get; set; }

    public List<LogInList> GetNr()
    {
        List<LogInList> Nr = new List<LogInList>();
        Nr.Add(new LogInList { AnsNr = 101 });

        return Nr;
    }

}
```

In my form, I've a button.. When you click it a form pops up. What you've to do is to write down the correct number from the List in the LogInList. That's what I'm trying to do anyways, I can't get it to work. The code for the button in the form looks like this:

```
public partial class LogIn : Form
{
    LogInList Log = new LogInList();


    public LogIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inMatningTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Log.AnsNr);
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while now.. I can't seem to make it. Please help me! I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'` errors all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare string (text in textbox) with Int32 value. You missed what should be converted to integer:

```
if (Log.AnsNr = Convert.ToInt32(inMatningTextBox.Text)) // remove ;
{

}
```

Or better use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method to check if user entered text which can be converted to integer number:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(inMatningTextBox.Text, out value))
    {
       // show error message, because text is not integer
       return;
    } 

    if (value == Log.AnsNr)
    {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you need integer value, then its better to use [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/57dy4d56%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control instead of TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! One question Sergey, I'm not getting any errors. But nothing happens when I click the OK button. It's like it doesn't register the input in the textbox? It does register if I type characters, I do get my error messagebox. But it doesn't register if I do enter the correct number (101, that is).

Comment: @user3168583 have you replaced *do your stuff* part with code which should be executed if correct number is entered? Also keep in mind - in code you provided newly created `Log` instance will have `AnsNr` equal to `0`

Comment: In the 'do you stuff' I got this.Close(); now. Nothing happens, though.

Comment: @user3168583 then entered value is not equal to `Log.AnsNr` value. Set a breakpoint and check these values in debugger

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway! The next step is to make it so I can enter 101 then... ;p

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few minor issues:

```
if (inMatningTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Log.AnsNr)
```

1. You are assigning the result of `Convert.ToInt32` to the `inMatningTextBox.Text`. I think you want to compare them.
2. You are comparing an `int` to a `string` value
3. There is a `;` at the end of the if statement.

I think you want this:

```
if (inMatningTextBox.Text == Log.AnsNr.ToString())
{

}
```